# Compare Percent Change values inside a for loop

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, tkinter, yfinance

I have a list like below
[image]
I want to be able to compare the percent change of QQQ at 9:35 to various other stocks like AAPL and AMD at the same time. So check if percent change of AAPL at 9:35 is greater than percent change of QQQ at 9:35. Same thing for AMD at 9:35 and then at 9:40 and then 9:45 and so on.

I want to do this via python
This is what i have so far but not quite correct

```
import pandas as pd
import time
import yfinance as yf
import datetime as dt
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
from collections import Counter
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import os
from pandas import ExcelWriter
d1 = dt.datetime(2020, 8, 5,9,00,00) 
d2 = dt.datetime(2020, 8, 5,16,00,00)


pc=Counter()
filePath=r"C:\Users\Adil\Documents\Python Test - ET\Data\Trail.xlsx"
stocklist = pd.read_excel(filePath)

for i in stocklist.index:
    symbol=stocklist['Symbol'][i]
    date=stocklist['Date'][i]
    close=stocklist['Close'][i]
    pc=stocklist['PercentChange'][i]

    if (pc[i]>pc['QQQ']):
        print(pc[i])
```

Comment: Please, note that SO is not a code by demand site. You should provide your attempts ([How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))

Comment: Sorry for posting without code, but i have not gotten very far

Comment: I am not totally sure what you are trying to do here.  Could you draw or explain what kind of output you are looking for here?  My best guess is you want a table that shows you if something did better or worse than QQQ per timestamp?

Comment: Yes so i want to see if within a given time 5 min time period if a stock performed better than QQQ

Answer (score 0):

Alright,

I got from a comment, an explanation of what the OP wants:

> Yes so i want to see if within a given time 5 min time period if a
> stock performed better than QQQ

First thing you need to do, is make it so you can look up your information by the time and symbol.  Here is how I would do that:

```
my_data = {}

for i in stocklist.index:
    symbol=stocklist['Symbol'][i]
    date=stocklist['Date'][i]
    pc=stocklist['PercentChange'][i]
    my_data[symbol, date] = pc
```

That makes a dictionary where you can lookup percent changes by calling `my_data['ABCD', 'datetime']`

Then, I would make a list of all the times.

```
time_set = set()
for i in stocklist.index:
    date = stocklist['Date'][i]
    time_set.add(date)
times = list(time_set)
times.sort()
```

If you are pressed for computer resources, you could combine those two loops and run them together, but I think having them separate makes the code easier to understand.

And then do the same thing for symbols:

```
sym_set = set()
for i in stocklist.index:
    date = stocklist['Symbol'][i]
    sym_set.add(date)
symbols = list(sym_set)
symbols.sort()
```

Once again, you could have made this set during the first for-loop, but this way you can see what we are trying to accomplish a bit better.

Last thing to do, is actually make the comparisons:

```
for i in times:
    qs = my_data['QQQ', i]
    for j in symbols:
        if qs != 'QQQ':
            which = "better" if my_data[j, i]>qs else "worse"
            print(j + " did " + which + " than QQQ at " + i)
```

Now, this just prints the information out to the console, you should replace the print command with however you want to output it.  (Also, I assumed higher was better; I hope that was right.)

Comment: Thanks for your response. So when i get to print my_data['QQQ',i] i get this error     KeyError: ('QQQ', Timestamp('2020-08-05 10:00:00'))

Comment: Make sure that the way you call entries from `my_data` and the way you entered entries in to it are exactly the same.  My guess is that `stocklist['Symbol'][i]` doesn't give exactly `QQQ` or something like that?